# How to echo variables within awk to create a new file

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a `test_1.fastq` file below and the code to split the file by matching the header. In addition to this, I want to add another line of code like `echo "@RG\tID:"arr[1]"\tPL:illumina\tPU:${SM}" > ${SM}."arr[1]"."lane".rgfile"` .  Basically, I want to create a new file by printing the echo statement appending the content of `"arr[1]"."lane"` in the code below. So, In addition to what my code produces, I also want to create three additional files `${SM}."arr[1]"."lane".rgfile"`. What do I need to do for this?

Code I have:

```
FQ_OUT1="test_1.fastq"
SM="sample1"
awk -v sm="$SM" '
BEGIN{FS = ":"} 
/^@HS2000/{
  split($1,arr,"_")
  sub(/^@+/,"",arr[1])
  lane=$2
  close(outputFile)  
  outputFile=sm"."arr[1]"."lane".fastq"
}
{
  print >> (outputFile)
}' ${FQ_OUT1}
```

test_1.fastq:

```
@HS2000-1015_160:7:1108:13370:100570/2
CTTGACTGCCAGAGACGCTCCTTTGCAATGCCTTCCGGTAACCAAATTTTTGGGCACAACACACAGCTGGCCTTCATTTCTTCAGGGGCTGGTAAACAGA
+
@@@ADFFFHHHFD=EF@:GHIIFHH<ECHGF@DDBB:6@D60?F=888)8='--(=5@EAE5?'(..((.;?@>>A>3;@####################
@HS2000-1015_160:5:2306:10070:71746/2
GAACCTCAAGGACTATTGGGAGAGCGGCGAGTGGGCCATCATCAAAGCCCCAGGCTACAAACACGACATCAAGTACAACTGCTGCGAGGAGATCTACCCC
+
@CCFFFFDHGHFHIJJJJJJGGGIIJJIGHI@FHGIIGHHEFGHHFFFFFBCDDDDDCDDDDDDDD;@BDCCDACDD@>ACCDDDDBDB<BA?C@CC@BD
@HS2000-1015_160:6:2116:4077:79041/2
GGTCCCCGCCTACGCCCACTGGGTTGGTGCACCTGGTGGTGGTGGCCGCCAAGAAGCTGGTGAACCGCCTCCAAGTGGCTCCCAAGACGCAGCTGGATGA
+
CCCFFFFFHHFHHJHJJJJJJJJGGHJHIGAGIIJIFHJ;@F;CHHFHFDDDDDCDDCDD9CCCDDBDDBBDDCDACDD8@BD3>?BCDBDDDACCDC@>
@HS2000-1015_160:5:2113:11446:94436/2
CGTCAGGGCCAACCCCGCCCCACCCTGACCCTACCTGGCACCCCTCACCTGTGGCCTGCCAGCACAGCCTCGCCCCTGCTGGCCAATGTGTCCCCCGTCA
+
?@@DA@DDFHH?DHI)<@@FHDBGGCHCBDH;DFA<)6.=7D;@CBCHD)).7@=>;?==AABC95<(5(5309@D########################
@HS2000-1015_160:6:2209:18284:44195/2
TAAAATGTCACAAAGCTGGAAACTCTTCCCTATCACAAACCAAAACTTAAAAGGACGTTACCTGGCTGGGTCTAAACTCCACATAACTCGCTTGCAGTTG
+
CCCFFFFEHHHGHJIIIJJIJJHIIJEHJJHIJJJIIJJIJIJJIJIIHJJIJGGHGHGIIHHIIIIHFH@DFFFDEEEECDDDCDDDDBDDBBDCDACC
@HS2000-1015_160:7:1215:18781:100685/2
ATAAAACAGTAAACAAAATAAAGTCAGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTAAAGAACAAAATGAAACTTGAGGGAAAACTTCATGGAGTTACAGTTTATCCTGATA
+
CCCFFFFFHFHHFJJJJIIGIGI<CFHHIIJJJJJIJJHFDDD=ACC(38+9CB?:(>C(+:@>(4?05<?C?###########################
@HS2000-1015_160:6:1215:6292:43622/2
GGGTCCTGAGACCTGAGGGACCATTGGCCCTCTTCTGGCTTGCTTATCCTTTGTACCTGATGGCCAATGAATGTCAGAGATGGTCCTGTCTCCATCCAGT
+
BCCDFFFFHGHHHJJJIIJJJJJIJJJGIJIJJIHIIJJIEFHEIJJJJIGIGIIIIIJHFHIJJJJIHGHEC?BCEFFFEECCCEACCCCDDDDDDCCC
```

Comment: Could you please be little more clear in your question sorry but it's not clear as of now. Like which additional file and with what content you are creating?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Hi, you helped me before on this. So basically I need to create text files appending `"@RG\tID:` and `"arr[1]"` and  `\tPL:illumina\tPU:${SM}"` as the content and direct them to this file `${SM}."arr[1]"."lane".rgfile"`. So each `${SM}."arr[1]"."lane".rgfile"` file will have only 1 line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to print only 1 line into new output file, considering that line should be added one time and when output file name is getting created on limes which are starting with `@HS`, if this is the case then try following. As per OP's comments OP wants to print `\t` ad a literal hence edited solution as per that here.

```
FQ_OUT1="test_1.fastq"
SM="sample1"
awk -v sm="$SM" -v tab='\\t' '
BEGIN{FS = ":"} 
/^@HS2000/{
  split($1,arr,"_")
  sub(/^@+/,"",arr[1])
  lane=$2
  close(outputFile)  
  outputFile=sm"."arr[1]"."lane".fastq"
  outputFile2=sm"."arr[1]"."lane".rgfile"
  print "@RG" tab "ID:"arr[1] tab "PL:illumina" tab "PU:"sm > (outputFile2)
  close(outputFile2)
}
{
  print >> (outputFile)
}' ${FQ_OUT1}
```

***Fixes in OP's attempt:***

- OP needed tab to printed as literal character so I have created `-v tab="\\\\t"` `awk` variable to have it in escaping way to be treated it as a literal character.
- Created new variable for output file named `outputFile2` which will create `.rgFile` for user.
- That rg file will be having only 1 line because statement is under condition if line starts from `@HS`.
- Though rg file will have only 1 line but I am using `close` to close it in backend for safer side.

---

---

***Logic of creating output files in `awk`:*** This may help anyone to know how to create output files in `awk`.

- Always create `-v awk_var="$shell_var` for keeping it clean to pass shell variables to awk variables. Though there is another of using `'"` but by this way it looks cleaner to handle.
- Always close the output file, see whenever `awk` writes anything to output files it keeps opening them in backend, so its better to close them to avoid error "too many files opened", though new versions of gawk handles that too, but as a good practice you could do it.

Comment: It is not creating any `.rgfile`

Comment: @MAPK, could you please do mention what should be contents of `.rgfile`? I actual content form not in command form please.

Comment: The `.rgfile` should only contain one line `echo "@RG\tID:"arr[1]"\tPL:illumina\tPU:"sm`

Comment: @MAPK, Please check now, I just copy/pasted and corrected your attempt, in `awk` to print we have `print` function not `echo` :)

Comment: This is great-thank you! Just one more thing though--I just need to have `\t` as string. i.e I don't want to evaluate it as tab.

Comment: Make `\t` into `\\t`

Comment: @MAPK, Added a variable which will print literal character into the output file, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - you have another satisfied customer and budding `awk` user -- well done.

Comment: @MAPK, I have added very detailed explanation for creating output files and fixes too, that may help you and anyone who is referring this thread in future, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have one more question: If I need to append one more variable say `$PR`, do I just declare it here `awk -v sm="$SM" pr="$PR" -v tab="\\\\t" '`?

Comment: @MAPK, yes please do it in that way then it should be good

Comment: Remember our previous discussion about always using single quotes around strings in shell unless you NEED to use double quotes becaues you need the shell to do something with the quoted string? Well,not following that rule is what's causing you to need 4 backslashes instead of 2 because you're ASKING the shell to interpret the string by using double quotes instead of single but then escaping the backslashes to STOP the shell from interpreting them! Use `-v tab='\\t'` instead of `-v tab="\\\\t"`. Also consider using a literal string, e.g. `tab='\t' awk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["tab"]}'`